# Publish website stopped working after upgrading to Visual Studio 2012.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, publishing

Ok, after upgrading my Visual Studio from 2012 to Visual Studio 2012.2 (http://www.asp.net/vnext), I cannot publish my website.

When right clicking on my web project and click "Publish Web Site", I get a different window than I used too. However, I've set up my publish profile like this:

[image]

Then I get dependency errors, as you can see here (yeah, no discussion about the DropBox physical path, that shouldn't be the problem):

[image]

I can easily build the project, and I can also publish when it's publishing to DEBUG mode.

You can see my SLN file here, and all the links seem correct. The only doubt I have is the Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath, as that's the old path it used. :

```
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "Client", "Client\", "{E9447A39-3F6B-4603-B476-FB72BDB41015}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5"
        ProjectReferences = "{92655DFC-29BE-4EEE-A211-E96811E113AA}|GKBusiness.dll;{BFD0BEE2-D00B-4F25-A3D4-D6C5351FA6E4}|GKDatabase.dll;{A4A80063-3996-4B53-992A-0ED1C3D78959}|Utils.dll;{D998D4C0-A7C1-495C-A40B-3926F3CF593A}|MathLibrary.dll;{7F454D7D-8AD6-49A2-88C6-6DD569168618}|Common.dll;"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/Client"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "Client\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\Client\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/Client"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "Client\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\Client\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        VWDPort = "16481"
        DefaultWebSiteLanguage = "Visual C#"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "GKBusiness", "GKBusiness\GKBusiness.csproj", "{92655DFC-29BE-4EEE-A211-E96811E113AA}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "GKDatabase", "GKDatabase\GKDatabase.csproj", "{BFD0BEE2-D00B-4F25-A3D4-D6C5351FA6E4}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Utils", "Utils\Utils.csproj", "{A4A80063-3996-4B53-992A-0ED1C3D78959}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "MathLibrary", "MathLibrary\MathLibrary.csproj", "{D998D4C0-A7C1-495C-A40B-3926F3CF593A}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Common", "Common\Common.csproj", "{7F454D7D-8AD6-49A2-88C6-6DD569168618}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "GKTest", "GKTest\GKTest.csproj", "{8BA66640-32FE-4DE1-B527-8986BD3F8713}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Solution Items", "Solution Items", "{2394BF74-243E-4521-9E2C-AEDC2AFB0D97}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        GodeKarakterer.vsmdi = GodeKarakterer.vsmdi
        Local.testsettings = Local.testsettings
        TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings = TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

I really don't have any idea what's wrong. But I certainly would love to be able to publish my website!

I have tried to restart Visual Studio, rebuild solution, clean the solution and restart the computer.

Thanks Microsoft - I enjoyed the update.. Grrrr! :-(

Comment: Have you copied all external references(DLLs) in the new folder created by Visual Stuio 2012?

Comment: @Obama : What new folder? :-) Nothing is copied into the path I've provided in VS.

Comment: okay so try to reload the references again cause the shared folder on dropbox can cause the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

I've had some nasty issues with the publish options in Visual Studio 2012 as well.

A few things you might want to try:
- Remove the publish profile (also check filesystem).
- Clean solution.
- Close Visual Studio.
- Restart your PC (to kill all webserver processes).
- Clean temp. files under C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\.
- Start Visual Studio.
- Build.
- Recreate publish profile.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you need to abandon **Visual Studio 2010** or **11** permanently, and do not uninstall either of them. It seems you'll re-break **Visual Studio 2012** if you open a solution in them.

1. Open the start menu and type *"%AppData%"* and enter to get to your **Application Data Folder**.
2. Go to the *"Roaming"* folder if you weren't automatically placed in that folder.
3. Open the *"Microsoft"* folder.
4. Open the *"VisualStudio"* folder.
5. You'll see a folder named *"11.0"* the VS 2012 folder and also *"10.0"* the VS 2010 folder.
6. Delete or rename the *"10.0"* folder.
7. Delete or rename all the other folders that are not the *"11.0"* folder.
8. Restart **Visual Studio 2012**.

And see if your **Visual Studio 2012** will work.. Good luck!